# Cabal fetch dependencies for current package

Tags: haskell, cabal

I wrote a package that I am trying to build.  For reasons, I do not want to install it on my laptop.  I want to download all of its dependencies and install it on another computer.  How can I do that?  If I run

```
$ cd my-package
$ cabal fetch .
```

cabal says `no packages requested`.  If I do

```
$ cabal fetch my-package.cabal
```

it does read the cabal file, but then it actually tries to download packages that don't exist on hackage, but are in my sandbox.

Comment: Where do you want to perform the compiles - on your computer or the other computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
cabal fetch `cabal install --dependencies-only --dry-run | sed 1,2d`
```

You might want to do it in a fresh sandbox so it doesn't skip dependencies that are already installed.

Aren't *nix tools great?

Comment: This is very close, but I had to adjust the `sed` command.  Thank you!

Comment: Adjust it to what?

Comment: @IvanPerez Just run `cabal install --dependencies-only --dry-run` and eyeball the output. Most of the lines will be a package name and version number like `my-great-package-3.2.0.0`, but there will be a few lines that obviously don't fit that pattern. Use whatever tool you're comfortable with to strip out those lines.

Comment: I was asking @nomen.

Thanks, although "check by yourself" does not help. I'm happy using `sed`, that's not the point at all. Another way of asking @nomen what I asked is "Is what you changed something ad-hoc for your case, or something that could be helpful for others? If it's the latter, could you explain what it is?"

Comment: @IvanPerez Do you believe that I did not answer those questions? I believe I did: I explained what might have to change for other people, and gave (what I thought was) a helpful explanation of how to figure out what to do to recover from the differences between my machine and theirs. Indeed, I think "check by yourself" is more likely to help than "do whatever nomen says he did two years ago and hope he remembered it right and that it works for you, too".

Comment: @DanielWagner Please stop this. I was really asking nomen. Neither of your comments added any useful information. I'm not trying to insult you. I'm not here to pick a fight. I'm just talking to someone else, to see if s/he has something useful to add.

Your command worked for me, and I was just trying to understand what might have to be changed in other cases.